# How to add "Encoding" parameter to Word Document SaveAs function in VBS?

Tags: scripting, vbscript, ms-word, document

In vbs, how can i add "Encoding" parameter to save as in ASCI format?

```
Set sample = CreateObject("Word.Application")
sample.Visible= True
sample.DisplayAlerts= False

Set sampleDoc =sample.Documents.Open("....\asd.docx")
...
...
...
sampleDoc .SaveAs("...\chancedDoc.docx")
```

Comment: A .docx is a binary file (a zip) so converting it to "ascii" doesn't make much sense, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @AlexK. complete code makes changes in a word document by replacing strings. But after changes and SaveAs, utf8 char problem occures in letters like ü,ğ,şç,ö.. Changing documents encoding ASCII is the only solution that i could find in short time.

Answer (score 1):

As you look into the MsWord help in the VBA editor, you see that the `SaveAs` method on `Document` is used like:

`expression.SaveAs(FileName, FileFormat, LockComments, Password, AddToRecentFiles, WritePassword, ReadOnlyRecommended, EmbedTrueTypeFonts, SaveNativePictureFormat, SaveFormsData, SaveAsAOCELetter, Encoding, InsertLineBreaks, AllowSubstitutions, LineEnding, AddBiDiMarks)`

The 12th parameter is the encoding parameter. When you search for encoding types (look for `MsoEncoding Enumeration` in the help), you'll find `msoEncodingUSASCII | 20127 | United States ASCII.`

So you have to use the number 20127 for the specific United States ASCII encoding as the encoding parameter.